# Neural network training with train() in R is very slow on fast machine

Tags: r

I am running the following command on R:

```
tg <- expand.grid(layer1 = 22, layer2 =0, layer3 =0)
tc <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv" , number = 7, repeats = 5)
registerDoMC(cores = 30)
Model <- train( x~ ., data, method ="neuralnet", trControl = tc, tuneGrid = tg)
```

I am running the above on 32 cores, 64 Gb RAM on amazon instance.  The issue is that code runs for 2 hours with no output. When i change method to "nnet" it runs normally( i know that neuralnet requires more processing)

But i would stay for 2 hours with no outputs for "neuralnet" and "qrnn"
 Is this normal? Or there is something i do not know?

Comment: Could you try h2o and provide a reproducible case w/ input data size ,network architecture? I'd like to go deeper for performance optimization.

Comment: i tried h20, performance is so much faster. but still, is there any reason why "neuralnet" and "qrnn" take forever?                                         
i am training 1017209 rows with 14 predictors (response variable is included) and i choose hidden layers to be 26 (best rmse i could get.)

Comment: I will try your case tomorrow;) could you make a reproducible case w/ input data?

Comment: @Patric sorry for my ignorance, what do you mean with reproducible case w/input data?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and [ask]

Comment: Did you try to cut down the testing data or even run it in parallel?